# How do we justify small signal analysis of comparator while we know that the biasing condition for the input devices are different?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, analog, integrated-circuit, comparator

During the real operation of comparator, the input baseline is lower than the threshold voltage.
How do we justify small signal analysis of comparator while we know that the biasing condition for the input devices are different?
am I forgetting some basic theoretical understanding here?

Comment: Why would you want to justify it?

Comment: @Andyaka because, as I understand it, small signal is valid only around the biasing point. In the comparator case, the input devices are biased at different point.

Comment: All the action happens when the inputs are very close in value.

Comment: Depends on how you define your 'real' comparator. If you are using an op-amp to model and have split supplies (+/- rails), the small signal gain is centered right at the 0 input point -- all devices are biased appropriately. Most ideal texts start with this model.

Comment: Small signal analysis is only valid when the circuit behaves **linearly**. A comparator does that only when the input voltage (difference) is near zero. I would generally **not care** about that behavior as it is not a state in which the comparator spends much of its time. A comparator spends most of its time in its non-linear state. Also the time response behavior (speed) of a comparator is mainly determined by slew-rate which is a **large signal** behavior.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie that is what I though as well. But many books and references I read consider small signal speed, i.e., BW. This makes me confuse, especially during sizing. any suggestion for this? So far, I keep L small and increase W to reduce mismatch.

Comment: It's true that large signal slew rate is a factor, but decision (switching) and settling time is a function of resistance and capacitance. The resistance is defined by the small signal gm (inverse). So fast transitions are dependent on this value. Mismatch is function of area (large L*W => better matching). So large gm faster, but that also requires low L. There's tradeoffs here. These design choices are governed around the small signal analysis and center of the decision threshold point. Your thoughts seem ok on that.

Comment: @pat Thanks for the confirmation. So my tradeoff is between small signal speed (i.e., BW) and mismatch? How about the second pole position? where should I put it?

Comment: 2nd pole is usually best pushed out far from 1st You want to avoid too much ringing and problems associated with non-dominant poles occurring before gbw. I would simulate step response and optimize around speed and settling characteristics. Slew Rate is an issue, but the assumption is you have enough not to affect linear settling characteristics.

Comment: @pat Hi, if you'd like to write the comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3):

The comparator isn't 'active' when the inputs are more than a few mV different in voltage, it's saturated to one rail or the other. The important parameters, propagation delay and input offset, are a function of how the comparator amplifier behaves when in the linear region.

Answer (score 1):

When any amplifier saturates the gain is zero.

When analyzing the small-signal performance of a comparator, we assume it is not saturated and thus operates in the linear region, which is rather difficult as it is not unity gain compensated to do so but may perform well in an open loop with low offset.

This means comparators are not designed for linear operations and linear Op Amps are not designed to be good high-speed comparators.  We like to call comparators "slicers" or "limiters".